# Could not find the button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i was trying various "find element by" methods to find a button that i need to click

```
<button data-test-modal-close-btn aria-label="Dismiss" id="ember1106" class="artdeco-modal__dismiss artdeco-button artdeco-button--circle artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view">flex
```

The html code has been mentioned above

and i tried access it through id but the ember under the id will randomly shuffles it number each time. so i red a answer on internet that i can use xpath to find aria label

```
close_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[aria-label=Dismiss]")
close_button.click()
```

but its helpless. can someone help me on this

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `css selector` is wrong basically you are missing `button`, try below code :

```
close_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[aria-label=Dismiss]")
close_button[0].click()
```

also since you have mentioned `ember1106` is dynamically,  generated

the below css may help you :-

```
button[id^='ember']
```

also you can try this :

```
button[aria-label='Dismiss'][class*='dismiss']
```

also try with explicit wait :-

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label=Dismiss]"))).click()
```

**imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: explict wait worked well. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Your locator is wrong, it should be `button[aria-label=Dismiss]`.
Also, you should use `find_element_by_css_selector`, not `find_elements_by_css_selector`.
Since `find_elements_by_css_selector` returns a list of web elements, not a single element you can click directly.
So, your code can be

```
close_button = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[aria-label=Dismiss]")
close_button.click()
```

or

```
close_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[aria-label=Dismiss]")[0]
close_button.click()
```

Comment: i got a error trying both of them saying that Message: element click intercepted: Element <div id="ember907" class="full-width artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view">...</div> is not clickable at point (258, 591). Other element would receive the click: <div aria-hidden="false" id="ember1029" class="artdeco-modal-overlay artdeco-modal-overlay--layer-default artdeco-modal-overlay--is-top-layer  ember-view">...</div>

Comment: but the problem has been solved by using the line(wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label=Dismiss]"))).click()). Thanks for the help